# Using Kinvey.Social to login with an Angular App and Promise API

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, kinvey

I've been using the Kinvey HTML5 library to try to build a client-side app that uses Google identities for Login.  Everything seems to be fine as far as the Oauth transaction is concerned, but I'm trying to toggle the visibility of my login button using a scope parameter and within the callback to the Kinvey `connect` method, Angular doesn't seem to be detecting the change.

The service:

```
  connect: function(successFn, failureFn) {
    return Kinvey.Social.connect(null, 'google',
      {
        success: successFn,
        failure: failureFn
      });
  }
```

The directive for the login link:

```
    $scope.login = function() {
      Login
        .connect(function(response) {
          $scope.loggedIn = true;
        },
        function(response) {
        });
    }
```

And the directive template:

```
<div>
  <button ng-hide="loggedIn" type="button" class="btn" ng-click="login()">Login with Google ({{loggedIn}})</button>
  <div class="btn-group btn-small" ng-show="loggedIn">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      Hello, {{user.socialData.name}} <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="/profile">My Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="/performance">My Performance</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="/logout" ng-click="logout()">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

The goal is to toggle the visibility of the login button vs. the visibility of the drop down.  I see no reason why what I'm doing shouldn't work.  Even using `$timeout` to simulate the changing of the `loggedIn` value produces the correct behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular needs to be notified when the external `Kinvey.Social` service returns so it can trigger a $digest cycle.   This can be done with the [`$apply()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) function of `$scope`

```
$scope.login = function() {
  Login
    .connect(function(response) {
      $scope.$apply(function() { $scope.loggedIn = true; });
    },
    function(response) {
    });
}
```

When using angular's own `$http` service it handles this for you but when using something external this is how angular knows to run a dirty check cycle which should trigger the `ng-show` directive you're using.

Comment: This certainly works, thanks.  I'm confused a bit about the kinvey API, and maybe I just don't understand promises correctly.  What is the need for the async callbacks if a promise is returned by kinvey?

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with the kinvey API myself or whether that call is returning some kind of [promise](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) but in this case the important thing is not how the asynchronous chaining is handled (it looks like just a typical callback) but *what happens* when the async action completes...  that where it's important to notify angular that something has changed and it needs to update bindings and **that's** why the `$scope.$apply()` is needed here.